# Direct object confusion: "ему" or "силу"?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

Thank you for any help in advance.

"Трениро́вки дали ему́ силу и уве́ренность."

In the above, I understand that емý is in the dative and силу и уве́ренность are in the accusative.

I ask why силу и уве́ренность are in the accusative when ему́ seems to me to be the direct object.

It is understanding that if емý is in the dative case then it cannot be the direct object.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: There's nothing to explain because you've done it nicely all by yourself.

Comment: Why are using accent on eму but not on силу?

Comment: @shabunc *си́лу slipped my mind, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just like in English:

> Training has given him strength and confidence.

"Strength and confidence" is the direct object while "him" is the indirect object.

Same in Russian:

> Тренировки дали ему силу и уверенность.

Direct object: силу и уверенность.

Indirect object: ему.